# Python regex endline

Tags: python, regex, line

I am trying to search a string, which I know is always a sentence, to find the three words that come before and  three words that come after a comma. Is regex the right way to do this AND how do you account for the fact that sometimes you will be at the beginning and end of a sentence and there will not be 3 words?

Thanks for the help, trying to learn regex.

Comment: Give some examples please. I don't think I fully understand what you exactly mean here.

Comment: I have a sentence:  "The brown fox jumped over the red barn,and found the chickens".  I need to find 3 words, and only words, to the left of the comma(the,red, and barn) and 3 words to the right of the comma (and, found, the). The matches cannot be anything but words

Comment: What if you have something like "The brown fox jumped over the red barn, and found 10 chickens." Is `10` counted as a word?

Comment: No it should be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, that one's a bit long, but I guess it works:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "The brown fox jumped over the red barn, and found the chickens."
>>> res = re.findall(r'(\b[a-z]+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b[a-z]+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b[a-z]+\b)?[^a-z]*,\s*(\b[a-z]+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b[a-z]+\b)?[^a-z]*(\b[a-z]+\b)?', string, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> res
[('the', 'red', 'barn', 'and', 'found', 'the')]
```

This will ignore numbers as well, for strings such as:

```
string = "The brown fox jumped over the red barn, and found 10 chickens."
```

To give:

```
[('the', 'red', 'barn', 'and', 'found', 'chickens')]
```

For things like:

```
string = "The brown fox jumped over the red barn, and fled."
```

It gives:

```
[('the', 'red', 'barn', 'and', 'fled')]
```

And same for words before the comma.

`\b` refers to a word boundary and will match only at the end of a word (letter, or number).

`[a-z]+` refers to a character class, namely all the letters from `a` to `z`. The `+` at the end indicates that this character class is repeated more than once, thus fulfilling the match of a full word.

`(\b[a-z]+\b)` is a capture group (notice the brackets) and will be stored in result. Adding a question mark at the end will indicate a possible occurrence (i.e. will match if it exists, and it won't match if it doesn't exist, thus how you can get results if there are less than 3 words before the comma).

`[^a-z]*` is a negated class, notice the caret just after the opening square bracket. It will match any character, not being letters `a` through `z`. The asterisk `*` indicates an occurrence of 0 or more times.

`,` is a literal comma.

`\s` is a space, tab, newline character. The asterisk after it still means an occurrence of 0 or more times.

`re.IGNORECASE`, as it suggests, will make the match case-insensitive.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will look up and try to figure out HOW this works.

Comment: If you look closely, there is a comma somewhere in the middle of the regex. You can use [this site](http://www.regex101.com/r/bI0yU6) to play around and there's even a very helpful description of how it's working on the left pane. Also, there is a lot of copy/pasting in that regex if you look closely. Try to identify the similar parts :)

Comment: @EnglishGrad Also, this won't work for words containing symbols and will count them as multiple words (e.g. `John's` will be counted as two words because of the apostrophe, much like `merry-go-round` will be counted as 3 words).

Comment: Jerry is there any reason the returned list would be null strings? I am getting a list back that looks like this: ['','','','','','']. The string I am checking is not empty. The string I am checking is: "Pleasure might cause her to read , reading might make her know."

Comment: @EnglishGrad Hmm, seems I don't know enough python yet. I wasn't sure when to use `r'` and when not to, but if you do here, it works as intended. I'll update my answer in a few. Now it's `re.findall(r' ...`

Comment: @EnglishGrad Awesome! :D I added a bit more detail on the regex if it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

for your example,

```
sen= "The brown fox jumped over the red barn,and found the chickens"
result_left=sen.split(',')[0].split()[-3:]

#result_left ['the', 'red', 'barn']

#for the right words
result_right=sen.split(',')[1].split()[:3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. What happens if the right boundary is less than 3? Does it only take what it can get or does it produce an error?

Comment: yep, take only what it can get.

Comment: This works well but it also grabs punctuation like "/", which is why I thought regex was probably the way